# Magento 2 : Remove Media And Product Info Block for Particular Product Type

Tags: magento2, product, blocks

I want to remove media block and product info block from PDP Page of particular product type. If I use in the following way,
`<referenceBlock name="product.info.media" remove="true" />`

then the media block gets removed from all the pages. But it should remove from only particular product type. In block, I made a check for productType in following way,

```
public function _toHtml()
{
    if (true) {
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
    return '';
}
```

But this is not working out. So how can I remove media and info blocks in PDP Page for particular product Type.

Answer (score 1):

**These are total types of product layout:**

```
catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml
catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml
catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml
catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml
catalog_product_view_type_virtual.xml
catalog_product_view_type_downloadable.xml
```

if you want to remove block particular type make a file in your **theme**:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
 <referenceBlock name="product.info.media.image" remove="true"/>
 <referenceBlock name="product.info.details" remove="true" />
</body>
</page>
```

After cache flush check it in your browser :-)

Comment: my file name is catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml. This effect all the prods of same type.

Comment: so every bundle product get the same effect @PavanKumar

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 provide diffrent xml file for diffrent types of product. You need to put your code into that file and it remove for that.

Diffrent product types file name are here.

```
 1. catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml
 2. catalog_product_view_type_virtual.xml
 3. catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml
 4. catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml
 5. catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml
```

Comment: my file name is catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml. This effect all the prods of same type.

Comment: Yes it remove this for all bundel type product, which you have ask into youe question.